# How to preform a delay in Xcode, unitests, without blocking the main thread?

Tags: xcode, multithreading, unit-testing, testing

I have a test that in it I have to do a REST call, to a server, 
and only after that call is recieved I can continue with the rest of the tests, 
I cannot use `sleep(x)` as it will block the main thread, and won't let the rest call to be done.

here is a code example to better explain:

```
let homeInteractor: HomeInteractor = HomeInteractor ()
homeInteractor.initSDK()

//// <<<<< DO A DELEY HERE FOR 5 SECONDS
//sleep(5) < CANNOT USE SLEEP AS IT WILL BLOCK THE MAIN THREAD

let loginInteractor: LoginInteractor = LoginInteractor ()
let loginViewController: LoginTableViewController = LoginTableViewController ()
let loginPresenter: LoginPresenter = LoginPresenter(controller: loginViewController)

loginPresenter.onLoginButtonPressed(usernameText: "username", passwordText: "password")

waitForExpectations(timeout: 10)

 XCTAssertEqual(loginPresenter.didUserLogin, true)
```

How can such a delay be achieved?

Comment: Check: http://cleanswifter.com/asynchronous-xcode-ui-testing/

Comment: @staticVoidMan this example is good only for cases were u just have one call todo, and check that specific one (which as u can see in my exqample i do) what i want todo before that is another initlize sdk call that i dont have any expectations to give it.

Comment: How do you know it's time to continue? I see no completion handlers.

Comment: @Mojtaba Hosseini homeInteractor.initSDK() is calling a network request that has the completion in the code itself obviosly not in the unitests

Comment: What about `onLoginButtonPressed` ? if you want 5 seconds delay (as `sleep(5)`) why you set the time out to 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// The code you didn't know when will finish
let homeInteractor: HomeInteractor = HomeInteractor ()
homeInteractor.initSDK()

// The time you guess it needs
let delay: TimeInterval = 5
let expectation = XCTestExpectation()

// Rest of the code after that delay
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {

    let loginInteractor: LoginInteractor = LoginInteractor ()
    let loginViewController: LoginTableViewController = LoginTableViewController ()
    let loginPresenter: LoginPresenter = LoginPresenter(controller: loginViewController)

    loginPresenter.onLoginButtonPressed(usernameText: "username", passwordText: "password")

    // fulfil expectations
    XCTAssertEqual(loginPresenter.didUserLogin, true)
    if loginPresenter.didUserLogin {
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
}

// Wait for it
wait(for: [expectation], timeout: delay)
```

Comment: hi, i'm getting some errors on this code, mainly , the .now() + delay gets > Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

Comment: Ok, I gave it more context.

Comment: hi @Mojtaba Hosseini can u try your code before posting, it errors on API VIOLATION on the wait for Expectations. i'm getting: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "API violation - call made to wait without any expectations having been set."

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to your project to write UITest for it and I dont't even have access to my mac now. I'm just trying to help and You should consider it as a template and get round of your issue. (Check out updated answer)

Comment: I think the problem with that example is that u cannot do, waitForExpectations(timeout: 10), without any expectations to be made. so it errors out

Comment: I changed the code a bit to fulfil the expectation, but comments above each part could lead you to answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you yea i modified it and it worked, but it's a great template ! thank you so much!